# Open Image in full screen android

Tags: android, image, gallery

I have an image in thumbnail in my application and I want to display full screen image like it shows, when you click on any image in gallery and it displays in full screen.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

You could launch the gallery app itself to view the image using below code snippet
You could give this a try.

> Intent intent = new Intent();
> intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
> intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()),"image/*");
>
> startActivity(intent);

Comment: can you post the whole exception stack

Comment: 01-06 12:21:54.847: E/MediaPlayer(32229): stop called in state 1
01-06 12:21:54.847: E/MediaPlayer(32229): error (-38, 0)
01-06 12:21:54.867: E/MediaPlayer(32229): Error (-38,0)

Comment: This does not necessarily show the image in full screen. Regardless the size of the image (even when it's much larger than the display), the default app will scale it down and there is always wasted space at the top and bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest in `onClick` method of your thumbnail, you can start a new `Activity` in fullscreen mode:

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

and pass the image uri or something which indicate the image source to the new activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YouActivity.this, FullImage.class);
intent.putExtra("imageUri", R.drawable.yourImage); // or the path to your image : "/sdcard/MyImages/image.png"
```

and than just show it in imageView of `FullImage` Activity like this :

```
ImageView icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inTempStorage = new byte[3*1024];

Bitmap ops = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
icon.setImageBitmap(ops);  // where icon is the imageView in your xml file
```

Comment: The image is not in my drawable. its in my gallery, i have selected an image from gallery and displayed as a thumbnail in my app. now i want to click on that thumbnail and want to open it in full screen like android,s default gallery works.

Comment: Ok, so I guess you have a path to your image, or at least there must be a way go get the right image. How are you selecting the thumbnail image?

Comment: Yes i have a path for that image and i want to display it using that path?

Comment: its giving me the NullPointerException on setImageBitmap(ops) method. i have check the file path its correct.