# I want to display an image in a new intent, the image is located in the drawables folder, by clicking an ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an imageview with the id of image and I want when it is clicked to show it in a new activity but it throws an `ActivityNotFoundException`. The image is inside my drawables folder I tried the answer from [Open Image in full screen android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739285/open-image-in-full-screen-android) but it didn't work.

```
    private String[] getList(Data data) {
    String[] restaurentList = null;

    switch (data.getCity()) {

        case "Βουκάτιο":
            restaurentList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chalkounia_restaurent);
            TextView btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/maps/place/%CE%92%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%BA%CE%AC%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BF+%CF%80%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%B1%CE%B2%CF%8C%CE%BB%CE%B1%CF%82/@38.6138245,21.519924,17z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x135e61d52624e3c3:0x58ffbd58963f6548!2zzpXOnyDOkc6zz4HOuc69zq_Ov8-FIM6Yzq3Pgc68zr_PhSwgzqDOsc-BzrHOss-MzrvOsQ!3b1!8m2!3d38.6138203!4d21.5221127!3m4!1s0x0:0xfa280e1b303b4737!8m2!3d38.6115948!4d21.5256091");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.deepanshu.tourguideapp/drawable_hdpi/voukatio");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }


                }
            });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Image in full screen android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739285/open-image-in-full-screen-android)

Comment: `Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.deepanshu.tourguideapp/drawable_hdpi/voukatio");`. That is a pretty impossible url. Not only that. There is nothing that indicates an image in drawables. And where should this be opened? You say in another activity. One of your activities?

Comment: It cant be opened in a new intent let's say from my phone gallery that shows the images for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to resolve:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.deepanshu.tourguideapp/drawable_hdpi/voukatio");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
     startActivity(intent);

        //context.startActivity(intent); maybe you have to use this, insted of startActivity(intent);
}else {
     Toast.makeText(this,"No app found.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: It didn't work when i was clicking the image nothing happened

Comment: can you use context.startActivity(intent); insted of  startActivity(intent); on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have ActifityA & ActivityB
In  First Activity (ActivityA) we can decode our image and send it through intent using putExtra:

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_image_name);     
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutStream); 
byte[] b = byteArrayOutStream.toByteArray();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("myImage", b);
startActivity(intent);
```

In ActivityB we can receive intent with byte array and apply directly as bitmap to ImageView:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] b = extras.getByteArray("myImage");

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

hope this will help.